# PS - Runbook AddTaxonomyField -Pushnotifaction error

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, azure

I'm trying to add some Taxonomyfield with Azure Automation.
1 field at the time is working well... but multiple at one gives me a constant error : push-notifactions are not enabled for this site.

```
Param
(
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [string] $siteUrl,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [string] $docLib
)


#CONNECTION
$tenantName = "mytenant"
$username = "uberadmin@mytenant.be"
$password = "prettysecretpassw" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$password

Connect-SPOService -Url https://$tenantName-admin.sharepoint.com/ -Credential $cred


#VARIABLES

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Credentials $cred
Add-PnPTaxonomyField -List $doclib  -DisplayName "DocType" -InternalName "Document Type" -TermSetPath "xxx|Document Type" -AddToDefaultView 
Add-PnPTaxonomyField -List $doclib  -DisplayName "Product" -InternalName "Product" -TermSetPath "xxx|Product" -AddToDefaultView 
Add-PnPTaxonomyField -List $doclib  -DisplayName "Team" -InternalName "Team" -TermSetPath "xxx|Team" -AddToDefaultView
```

Error (dutch)

> Add-PnPTaxonomyField : De functie voor push-meldingen is niet
> geactiveerd op de site   https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/EB010.
> At line:44 char:9  + Add-PnPTaxonomyField -List $l.Title -DisplayName
> $displayNam ...  +
>
> ```
> CategoryInfo : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPTaxonomyField], ServerException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Fields.AddTaxonomyField
> ```

Comment: can you execute `Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 41e1d4bf-b1a2-47f7-ab80-d5d6cbba3092` first and then your code to create fields and check ?

Comment: Oh Boy, thx @GautamSheth for this reply. I have been looking for PNPFeature 'notification' or something in that order, didn't find a thing.

This did the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome :). Have posted it as answer, you can upvote and accept it so that it may help others in the community. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like SharePoint sometimes throws intermittent error about the push notifications feature. Due to that, looks like your code isn't working as expected even though it is correct.

To fix that issue, you can enable the Push Notifications feature as below and then execute your code:

```
Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 41e1d4bf-b1a2-47f7-ab80-d5d6cbba3092
```

Reference  - [The push notifications feature is not activated on the site sharepoint 2013](http://sharepointstepbystep.blogspot.com/2014/06/the-push-notifications-feature-is-not.html)